# How can i edit and update /etc/hosts file using php

Tags: php, ubuntu, hosts

Dynamically i want to edit and update my `(/etc/hosts)` hosts file to add domain using php

I have tried with this code in php

```
exec ("sudo chmod 777 /etc/hosts");
fopen("/etc/hosts", "r")
```

I am getting the error `Warning: fopen(/etc/hosts): failed to open stream:` in php

Comment: I think your php needs the permission to access `/etc/` too

Comment: I think the problem is the [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Your exec() and fopen() must be properly synchronized.

Comment: @RahilArora `exec` is synchronous, so there's no race condition.

Comment: Is there any more to the error message? I suspect your PHP configuration restricts `fopen` to the document root, so it can't access `/etc`.

Comment: The problem is in the file permissions.

Comment: @mlinuxgada `/etc/hosts` has to be world-readable or many things would break.

Comment: also sometimes the `exec` is blocked by `php.ini` make sure you have enabled them..

Comment: @Barmar: This the only error message i am getting when i am trying to read the hosts file using fopen

Comment: Changing file perf of /etc may break things. 
If that php code is executed via cli, just run that with root user.
Or make a symlink to some file with read/write access.

Comment: Usually there's more, like `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @zzlalani: how do i enable exec in php.ini?

Comment: try this.. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/

Comment: @Barmar: $arrtext = file("/etc/hosts");
print_r($arrtext);exit(); using this code i am able to view my hosts file details

Comment: Please check your PHP error log again. For me it always adds a reason why it couldn't open the stream, e.g. `failed to open stream: Permission denied` or `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`